# whats the fastest way to find the densest region in an array or list?

Tags: python, statistics

I have an array of 1 million elements: 0 or 1:

```
 example = np.array([0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,...]
```

I need to find the area in the array that has the densest concentration of 1's. Continuing with the above example, the output might be the index where the dense region starts: `3` which would correspond to: `...1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,...` which would have a hit rate of `11/12` or `91.67%`.

Determining the densest region, of course, would probably be easiest if I specified a window length (ahead of time), but ideally, I wouldn't have to do that: it would just find the highest ratio of percentage of one's to length of region, but I also need it to compute quickly, so I'm assuming I'll have to specify a window length anyway.

I can naively do this with a loop or, even worse, a nested loop, but that's too slow for millions of numbers. So I wondered if there's some Numpy magic that could essentially identify a dense region or the highest summed region or something like that.

Does anyone know of a package that has this functionality? Numpy? scipy.stats? If I transform it into a matrix is there a way to some each region simultaneously or sometihng? thanks for your advice!

Edit:

Fixed window size constraint accepted! Say the window is `1%` of the total length of the array, how would I go about finding the 1% region (could be `1.5%` to `2.5%` for instance) that has the highest number ones in it out of all the possible regions (array length - 1).

Comment: The ratio of `1`s is 100% if you take the first series of 1 you encounter. So, you need to provide a better definition of 'densest'.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille, excellent point, perhaps, in that case, I would just have a minimum length that is acceptable.

Comment: That seems right. What about a maximum length too, then, to give a more accurate meaning to the term 'region'? A fixed length window would probably be easiest, though. Maybe you should decide on what exactly you want and edit your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the density of a region with a certain size using a convolution.  This will give you the start position of the *first instance* of the densest region for the input window size.

```
import numpy as np
def densest(array, size):
    density = np.convolve(array, np.ones([size]), mode='valid')
    return np.argmax(density)

example = np.array([0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0])

print( densest(example, 10) )
# 3
```

Answer (score 2):

Other more verbose and maybe slowest option:

```
import numpy as np

ary = np.array([0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0])

result = []
ones = {'idx': 0, 'count': 0}
for idx, x in np.ndenumerate(ary):
  if x == 1:
    ones['count'] += 1
    ones['idx'] = idx[0]
  if x == 0 and ones['count'] > 0:
    ones['idx'] = ones['idx'] - ones['count'] + 1
    result.append(ones)
    ones = {'idx': 0, 'count': 0}
```

It returns a dict with all the region with ones, index start and count:

```
print(result)
#=> [{'idx': 3, 'count': 7}, {'idx': 11, 'count': 4}, {'idx': 18, 'count': 1}, {'idx': 21, 'count': 2}, {'idx': 24, 'count': 1}, {'idx': 30, 'count': 1}, {'idx': 32, 'count': 1}]
```

Then you can pick the max:

```
print (max(result, key=lambda x: x['count']))
#=> {'idx': 3, 'count': 7}
```